# Passing an unknown function in a knockout binding (foreach) - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-binding-handlers

For a simple example, lets say this is my repeater:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: property1, attr: { onclick: some_unknown_function }"></li>
</ul>
```

I want whoever is using this code to be able to pass in a function of their choosing, NOT in the model itself that will run onclick - is that possible?  Would there be a way to assign it to the model and set it as the click binding?  I can't seem to figure this out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a pretty easy way, sometimes I forget how literal JS is...

Changed my repeater to this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: property1, click: myClick }"></li>
</ul>
```

And my model to this:

```
function Item(options) {
    var self = this;
    options = options || {};

    self.property1 = ko.observable(options.property1 || '');
    self.onclick = options.onclick || null;

    self.myClick = function () {
        if (self.onclick != null) {
            self.onclick()
        }
    }
}
```